# Rails 3.1 app in a subdirectory with IIS

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, iis

Does anyone have any idea how to set this up? I'm totally stuck. If there's a config option I can't find it, and I'm assuming that the answer isn't in routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else asking this: don't even consider it.